# Non experimental way to allow a client to gracefully cancel streaming service

Tags: java, grpc

Since all StreamObserver (CallStreamObserver, ServerCallStreamObserver) classes are marked as experimental https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1788 , What is a stable way to allow a client to gracefully cancel streaming service by signaling the server to stop sending messages?

Also, if I decide to use these classes to achieve this functionality, can I assume that I will be fine unless I upgrade grpc-java version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always call `onError()` on the `StreamObserver` returned by the stub. For server-streaming RPCs where the stub doesn't return a `StreamObserver`, you can start the RPC inside a `Context`.

```
CancellableContext withCancellation = Context.current().withCancellation();
Context prevCtx = withCancellation.attach();
try {
  stub.foo(request, responseObserver);
} finally {
  withCancellation.detach(prevCtx);
}
```

Then closing the `Context` will cancel the RPC:

```
withCancellation.close();
```

Comment: There was another answer posted on google grpc-io group

Comment: CarlM wrote on google group: bit.ly / 2yhshdr
You can assume this part of API will never change. The usage of that API is widespread enough that it would be infeasible to change it. If you are keen on using a Non experimental API, you can use the ClientCall & Server call directly, which have stable API. You could copy paste io.grpc.stub package and not worry about API changes. StreamObserver are thin wrappers on top of ClientCall and Server call. You can make your own "Observers" and pass them into the helper functions in io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls & ServerCalls, which have stable API.